# PSI : How to determine if Resource Plan in Project Server 2010 is checked out in c#?

Tags: c#, project-server, psi

anyone know how to check if a Resource Plan is checked out using the PSI? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the PSI web service [ResourcePlan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcresourceplan.resourceplan_di_pj14mref.aspx).

Just add the web service reference to your project and initialize a new soap client:

```cs
//init the soap client
ResourcePlanSoapClient resSvc = new ResourcePlanSoapClient();

//your project id
Guid prjGuid = new Guid("30937680-39FA-4685-A087-90C73376B2BE");

//read the status
ResPlanStatus status =  resSvc.ReadResourcePlanStatus(prjGuid);
```

The enum contains three states:

- Absent (not in use)
- Working (checked out)
- Published (checked in)

I hope this will help you

Regards Florian

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Going to post a related question about deleting/recreating the resource plan, maybe you'll know that one too!

Comment: Here is the link to the new question if your interested, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356845/psi-deleting-and-recreating-the-resource-plan-in-project-server-2010